# Tabbar scrolling jumps back

Tags: scrolling, tabbar

I am using tabbar and some settings for smooth scrolling which seem to conflict with each other in a weird way. Here is a minimal init.el file:

```
(package-initialize)
(setq mouse-wheel-scroll-amount '(1 ((shift) . 10) ((control) . 30)))
(require 'tabbar)
(tabbar-mode t)
(setq mouse-wheel-progressive-speed nil)
```

With these settings, if I now try to scroll a moderate length (600 long lines) tex file in the AucTeX mode, it jumps back, i.e. if I scroll, say, up, and look at the percentage bar, it goes 70,69,68,67, and then jumps back to 70,69,68,67,... If I move the point somewhere else and start scrolling again then it scrolls ok for a while but then again starts cycling around. Disabling tabbar mode makes the issue disappear. Is there maybe a setting that could prevent tabbar from affecting this scrolling behavior in such an annoying way?

I'm on OS X 10.12.5, Emacs 25.2, and the issue appears the same way if I use mouse or touchpad.

**UPD. thanks to @lawlist's comment, it suffices to open the tex file and just set `header-line-format` to a non-`nil` value.** The updated minimal init.el file now is

```
(setq mouse-wheel-scroll-amount '(1 ((shift) . 10) ((control) . 30)))
(setq mouse-wheel-progressive-speed nil)
```

Comment: I would recommend trying to narrow down the issue to the mere existence of a `header-line-format` and see if you still have a problem.  Without `tabbar` being active, you can set the `header-line-format` on a per-buffer basis to an arbitrary value such as `hello-world`.  If the problem persists with `hello-world` in the `header-line-format` and `tabbar` disabled, then you will be one step closer to tracking down the bug.  If not, then you know the conflict is with something else inside `tabbar`.

Comment: thanks @lawlist! It does help narrow the bug down, although I'm still not sure if this can be fixed somehow.